# How to lazy load dependencies in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection

In Angular 1 one could lazy load any dependency by using `$injector`. Complete example is [there](http://www.codelord.net/2016/11/10/circular-dependencies-in-angular-and-the-injector-service/). Gist of it is, that when service is needed one could simply obtain it by asking `$injector` like this:

```
const authService = $injector.get('AuthService');
```

How to do it in Angular 2?

---

Please note that this question is **not** about rewriting the problem to three or more services. This question is about keeping all classes (all being ng services) and about a way of obtaining dependencies after class (service) is constructed.

Comment: Did you search. There are already answers to this topic (with and without using the router).

Comment: I did. Found only "solutions" involving rewriting it to more services or some advices about interfaces which didn't seem to be related to the Angular 2 DI at all. If exactly same question was asked, please mark this one as a duplicate and link to the other question.